# How to Apply An Animation to Different Meshes?

Tags: animation, rigging, unity

Beginner here.

I have just modeled and rigged a character for use in a game. I have the file for the static, unmoving character on my computer.

[image]

I outsourced the animations for idle, run, walk, etc. because I suck at animation. I gave the artist the file for my static rigged character and he used this to do the work. I received back several different Blender files, each containing one animation.

My question is, how to I add all these separate animations to my single static rigged character? I intend to import the character, along with his string of animations, into Unity.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! :-D

This YouTube Video Clears it All Up:
[Creating and Editing Actions for Re-Use in Animations and Games](https://youtu.be/Gb152Qncn2s)